# How can we dynamically load a webpack module/bundle which is generated by webpack config's entry property

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to load a webpack bundle dynamically which is generated by webpack config entry property.

```
module.exports = {
 entry: {
   home: 'src/home.js',
   DemoComponent1: 'src/DemoComponent1.js',
DemoComponent2: 'src/DemoComponent2.js',
DemoComponent3: 'src/DemoComponent3.js'
 }

}

// code in home.js
const component = getDynamicComponent(); // can be any component
import(component).then(component => {
    this.state.selectedComponent = component;
});
```

Getting Following Error: 
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module 'DemoComponent1.js'

Comment: Dynamic import creates a bundle from the sub-tree of the file, your usage is weird.

Comment: You can `import('src/DemoComponent') ...` instead, and webpack will split that sub-tree from the main bundle

Comment: Sorry, edited my question. The component name need to be dynamic and I can't hardcode it in the code.